# NavigationBar BackButton's text if NavigationBar's title is too long

Tags: ios

I have a custom text as Back button but since iOS7 it's automatically shortened to default "Back" text or even removed at all. Is there any way to change that *default* "Back" text to something else? I would rather have it removed at all than replaced with "Back" text.

Answer (score 0):

Do with this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"YourTitle";
```

Comment: Back button will still get shortened/removed like that. As well as I might have segmentedControl or something else in the navigationbar ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom back button in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller that you want to navigate back to:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CustomTitle" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it get shortened/removed if navigation's bar title is too long and it can't fit there?

Comment: Yes. You asked if it's possible to customize the title such that it'll show something else instead of default "Back". Setting a custom back button allows you to do just that. i.e. you could always set an empty string if the title length is deemed too long for a particular view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that. For example, in `viewDidLoad()`

In swift:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Custom Title", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

In Objective-c:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: "CustomTitle" style: UIBarButtonSystemItem target: nil action: nil];
```

You can also set the title to "" if you want to delete the title and to only show the < symbol.

**Important**: you have to do this in the controller **from which** the segue starts.

For example, if the segue goes from **ViewController1** to **ViewController2**, you would have to write the previous code in the `viewDidLoad()` implementation of **ViewController1**